# GUI FTP and File Management for Linux VPS

Tags: linux, ftp, vps, graphical-user-interface

I'm interested in how I could remotely control FTP and file management on my Linux VPS with a GUI. I frequently transfer sites to my VPS for testing, and I'd much rather do it directly on the high bandwidth connection instead of my 10down, 2up Comcrap cable.

Comment: this is better suited to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) and will be automatically migrated.  if you register accounts on this site and on Server Fault, you'll be able to associate your accounts in your user profile, and will regain control of the migrated question automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If your system has an X server (Linux already has one; OS X has one on the install disk; Windows uses [Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/)) then you can do X forwarding over SSH so that you can run something like [gFTP](http://gftp.seul.org/) or [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) on the remote system.

If you're not terribly married to using the GUI (or can't be arsed to install an X server) then you can use [Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/) over SSH instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running a VPS, you are likely not running X-Windows by default. On Debian, installing the freenx-server package will install X-Windows and provide you with a secure way to connect to the remote GUI. After that, you can use any of the GUI-based FTP clients that @Ignacio mentions.